# Set Variable On First Run in java

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a java swing project that require login and password that need to be entered when run first time i.e. `setLoginFrame.java`.

for all the subsequent run it should run the `Login.java`

can't find a way other than file handling to store `login` and `password`..
I have no idea like how to do this..

Comment: Storing the username and password sounds like poor *security* to me; but what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not very risky data, then you can just use files for storage, then encrypt them separately if you wish.

Else, you can generate hashes of your strings with [MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) in the java.security package. Just call getInstance() as per the example. SH1 is generally seen as stronger encryption.

Comment: [SHA-1](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html) has been broken for a *decade*.

Comment: [No it hasn't](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86609/this-is-2015-has-sha1-been-exploited-or-cracked-yet), there is no strong evidence of it having been broken. Either way, it is not _easy_ to break, therefore I'd consider it an adequate encryption algorithm for someone who doesn't know what do with a user login and password.

Comment: A one way hash function isn't encryption, it's unclear on whether OP needs a reversible transform; but if Schneier says it's broken I'm not going to use it (the SHA-2 family still seems to be okay).

Comment: Also, from your link, the [SHAppening](https://sites.google.com/site/itstheshappening/).

Comment: Ah, interesting. It seems it's not trusted by big players anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You really should learn about security of data and [how to store passwords](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/). 
If you want to store data, there is always a [database](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) option. 
But if you are staying with storing in files, there is a lot of info in the web about how to do so. For example [here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-store-data-with-java/25483).